# How redraw labels in D3 maps?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I am following two tutorials to make a map in TOPOJson :

1. Display countries, borders and cities (dot & labels). [Tutorial here](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/).
2. Move and zoom the map. [Tutorial here](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/2322933).

I am able to display the pan, to pan, to zoom, but the names of the cities are not redrawn.

```
       var path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection)
      .pointRadius(2);

  /* What's hapenning here ? */
  var svg = d3.select("#vis").append("svg:svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw));

  /* Format projected 2D geometry appropriately for SVG or Canvas. */
  d3.json("uk.json", function(error, uk) {
    svg.selectAll(".subunit")
        .data(topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.subunits).features)
      .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit " + d.id; })
        .attr("d", path);

    svg.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(uk, uk.objects.subunits, function(a, b) { return a !== b && a.id !== "IRL"; }))
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("class", "subunit-boundary");

    svg.append("path")
        .datum(topojson.mesh(uk, uk.objects.subunits, function(a, b) { return a === b && a.id === "IRL"; }))
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr("class", "subunit-boundary IRL");

    svg.append("path")
      .datum(topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.places))
      .attr("d", path)
      .attr("class", "place");

    svg.selectAll(".place-label")
        .data(topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.places).features)
      .enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", "place-label")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + projection(d.geometry.coordinates) + ")"; })
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.geometry.coordinates[0] > -1 ? 6 : -6; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.geometry.coordinates[0] > -1 ? "start" : "end"; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; });

    svg.selectAll(".subunit-label")
      .data(topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.subunits).features)
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit-label " + d.id; })
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")"; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; });
  });

  function redraw() {
    // d3.event.translate (an array) stores the current translation from the parent SVG element
    // t (an array) stores the projection's default translation
    // we add the x and y vales in each array to determine the projection's new translation
    var tx = t[0] * d3.event.scale + d3.event.translate[0];
    var ty = t[1] * d3.event.scale + d3.event.translate[1];
    projection.translate([tx, ty]);

    // now we determine the projection's new scale, but there's a problem:
    // the map doesn't 'zoom onto the mouse point'
    projection.scale(s * d3.event.scale);

    // redraw the map
    svg.selectAll("path").attr("d", path);

    // redraw the labels
    svg.selectAll(".place-label");

    // redraw the x axis
    xAxis.attr("x1", tx).attr("x2", tx);

    // redraw the y axis
    yAxis.attr("y1", ty).attr("y2", ty);
  }
```

I have tried to add this line :

```
svg.selectAll(".place-label").attr("d", path);
```

in the redraw function but it did not worked.

Could you tell me which line should I add to refresh their positions ?

Here is my live code : [Plunker live example & code](http://embed.plnkr.co/8kaibYdv2nAoszRCGhma/)

Comment: You need to set the position in exactly the same way as when you're adding the labels, i.e. set the `transform` attribute.

Comment: Show us a fiddle of your project.

Comment: I have created a Plunker : http://embed.plnkr.co/8kaibYdv2nAoszRCGhma/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the labels move along with the map you need to do this:
On `redraw function`

```
  svg.selectAll(".place-label")[0].forEach( function(d){
    var data = d3.select(d).data()[0];//this will give you the text location data
    d3.select(d).attr("transform", "translate("+projection(data.geometry.coordinates)+")" )//pass the location data here to get the new translated value.
  });
```

For subunits do:

```
svg.selectAll(".subunit-label")
.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")"; })
```

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/M60XcUbi9w0LaKHiJp5b?p=preview)

Hope this works!